# ag grid with vue doesn't render style after horizontal scroll

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I have a problem after scroll right it is not rendering the style of the row
[image]

```
  // DefaultColDef sets props common to all Columns
  const defaultColDef = {
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    flex: 1,
    maxWidth: props.maxWidth,
    suppressMenu: true,
    tooltipComponent: CustomTooltip,
    lockPosition: true,
  };
```